# HANA SQL - Create multiple rows from one row based on calculation

Tags: hana

I have the following 2 records:

| Batch | Qty | QtyPer | PackNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 60 | 20 | 3 |
| Two | 20 | 10 | 2 |

I need to find a way to create multiple rows based on Qty/PackNum, such as:

| Batch | Qty | QtyPer | PackNum | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 60 | 20 | 3 | 1 |
| One | 60 | 20 | 3 | 2 |
| One | 60 | 20 | 3 | 3 |
| Two | 20 | 10 | 2 | 1 |
| Two | 20 | 10 | 2 | 2 |

I've tried using the WITH command to no avail.

Any Ideas?

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

one alternate is construct as dummy table or dummy sql with below structure and do the cross join on the pack_number. You could also try sql procedure with global/local temporary table

pack number, level
3,1
3,2
3,3
2,1
2,2

or
below is the pseudo sql

```
select it.*,dd.level from(
select 3 as pack_number , 1 as level from dummy 
union all 
select 3 as pack_number , 2 as level from dummy 
union all 
select 3 as pack_number , 3 as level from dummy 
union all 
select 2 as pack_number , 1 as level from dummy 
union all 
select 2 as pack_number , 2 as level from dummy 
....
) as dummy_data as dd
inner join 
input_tab as it
on dd. pack_number = it.pack_number
```